# PHP Objects and classes error

Tags: php, class, object, subclass

In my beginning PHP class, we are having our first go at Objects and classes.  My assignment question is:

1. Create (a) a parent class (aka “superclass”) named “Human” with one variable named “legs” and one function (aka “method”) named “walk”, (b) set the default value of “legs” to 2, and (c) make the “walk” function display “Human can walk.” when it is called.
2. Create (a) a child class (also known as “subclass”) named “Kids” which will inherits all members of the “Human” class, (b) create a variable “hands” of the Kids class and set its default value to 2, and (c) create a function named “jump” of the Kids class which displays a message “A kid can jump.”
3. Create an object of the “Kids” class named ”Kuma”, and (c) use the "Kuma" object to display the numbers of legs and call the “walk” function.

The result should print:

2 legs

Humans can walk.

2 hands

A kid can jump.

Here's my code so far.  I'm having difficult with the instructions in #3.

```
class Human {
var $legs = 2;
var $content = "<p>Humans can walk.</p>";

function Walk($Kuma) { 
    echo $this->legs . " legs";
    echo $this->content;
}
}

class Kids extends Human {
var $hands = 2;
var $content2 = "<p>A kid can jump.</p>";

function Jump($Kuma) {
    echo $this->hands;
    echo $this->content2;

}
}

$obj = new Kids(Kuma);
$obj -> Walk(Kuma);

?>
```

Comment: `$Kuma = new Kids();
$Kuma->Walk();`

Comment: Although the term "name" is used in 2 different contexts in your instructions (class name and instance name), I think what is being asked for "Kuma" is to name the instance:  `$Kuma = new Kids()`

Comment: First of all, you should start making indentions in your code!

Comment: @MarkBaker, I tried using `$Kuma = new Kids(); $Kuma->Walk();` The error is gone, but I can't get the last two lines of output: "2 hands" and "A kid can jump." Suggestions?

Comment: @MarkBaker Wow, thanks!  Just that easy.  Still learning...

Comment: What makes you think the `Walk()` and `Jump()` methods should also output `2 legs` or `2 arms`? I don't read that in the instructions at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Human {
    var $legs = 2;
    var $content = "<p>Humans can walk.</p>";

    function Walk() { 
       echo $this->legs . " legs";
       echo $this->content;
    }
 }

 class Kids extends Human {
     var $hands = 2;
     var $content2 = "<p>A kid can jump.</p>";

     function Jump() {
        echo $this->hands;
        echo $this->content2;
     }
 }

$kuma = new Kids(); // creating OBJECT kuma 

$kuma -> Walk(); // calling the walk function

?>
```

for example:

```
$object = new Human(); // creating OBJECT named object of CLASS Human
```

Comment: Hey, the 90' called, they want their syntax back.

Comment: @Jefffrey - see first sentence.

Comment: @J.D. I've added in the suggestion of $Kuma = new Kids(): $Kuma -> Walk(); but the output does not include the last two senetences of 2 Hands and A kid can jump.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Jefffrey, it justifies why I'm on here to learn...not be critisized

Comment: @CoPoPHP, it's a joke. Don't take it so hard. But seriously, forget `var` and remember to always specify the access of functions and variables with either `private`, `protected` or `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a few weird things in your example.  For example, I have no idea, from the instructions you gave, why you want the Walk and Jump methods to output information about hands and legs.

Here would be my suggestion:

```
class Human {
    public $legs = 2;
    public function walk() { 
        echo 'Human can walk.';
    }
}


class Kids extends Human {
    public $hands = 2;
    public function jump() {
        echo 'A kid can jump.';
    }
}

$Kuma = new Kids();
echo $Kuma->legs . " legs\n";
$Kuma->walk();
echo "\n";
echo $Kuma->hands . " hands\n";
$kuma->jump();
```

A few things to note:

- I have used good coding practice in declaring variables and method scope (in this case `public`).  Honestly, good coding practice would also have the class properties (legs/arms) be declared as `protected` and available only via getters/setters.
- I did not enforce any HTML formatting within the class (I actually just used end of line characters in my example which could be substituted with HTML line breaks or paragraphs or whatever you might need). I probably would have actually not even had the class itself be responsible for output when calling methods except that is explicitly asked for. (I would have simply done `return` of the raw text and let caller determine formatting for output).
- I remove hands/legs output from walk/jump.  This has nothing to do with those methods and should not be mixed.